# Vibrator not working after upgrading to ICS - Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, vibration

I have upgraded to the latest official version available through Kies. And I have noticed that after the update the vibrator of the phone is not working. Actually its working but not in Silent mode on receiving a call. When we switch to vibrating mode or at the boot-up the phone, the vibrator vibrates. So the vibrator is functional.

I have searched a lot and I could not find any valid solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Settings -> Sound** and make sure **Silent mode** is set to **Vibrate**, then in `RINGTONE & NOTIFICATIONS` section, check the option **Vibrate on ring**, then call yourself and it should vibrate.

Comment: @Ajmal Nice, you are welcome.